# Google analytics Using the API how can I tell where the actual url the user has come from?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the following to look at results from my Google analytics:

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?csw=1

i ve got it up and running ok but when i use ga:referralPath or ga:userdefinedvalue it says (not set)

I expected to be able to see where the user has come from for example:

if a user goes onto the dove site and wants to buy a product they click a buy now button which gives them the retailers, when they click on the retailer they are taken to the add to basket on the retailer site - where my UA code is.

I want to be able to see that they have come from the dove site - is this possible?

btw here's a good link to show how to see the full url (but at the moment i m getting (not set)) but if anyone knows how to get this working it would be perfect:

http://www.sebastienpage.com/2009/05/06/google-analytics-trick-see-the-full-referring-url/

Comment: Filters apply only on incoming data, not past data. Look at user defined value tomorrow, for data about today.
Also, double check that the dove site isn't hidding the referrer (use FF and Page Information menu on the landing page to check the referrer value, or Fiddler)

Comment: thanks i ll have a go at that i found - do you k now if GA has changed recently as before i could see the actual referral paths ..?

Answer (score 0):

After leaving the GA code on the site for a while we started getting the revenue results back and in ga:source and ga:refferalPath within the e commerce section i could see the results that i expected- one of the things that was changed was that we were told by the retailer who implemented our ga script was that they were getting a SSL certificate error - as we did not have one on our servers once this was added we seemed to be getting all the data through fine.